# Assist with MySql Query - Update based on select between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been hitting my head against the wall about this problem for the last 8 hours and I still can't find a solution.

This was my first post on stackoverflow, so sorry if I'm committing any kind of mistake writing this post.

Based on previous answers, I have to agree that CREAT VIEW might be a better and easier option than using UPDATE for my case.

I'll try to explain my problem:

Brief contextualization: I have a table with quality control results and another with the product specification. What I have to do, is to insert the specification in the results table row by row in order to make it easier for me to statistically treat a comparison between results and specs and plot charts. The main problem I encountered is that I have different specifications for the same product (they change over time) and because of that I have to insert different specifications in the result's table based on the result's date.
For Example: Let's say I have two Specs date: 2020-01-01 and 2020-05-01
If I have a result on 2020-01-03 I have to insert in this result row the spec of the 2020-01-01. However, if the result date is 2020-05-02 I have to insert the spec from 2020-05-01. (always the newest specification which is older than the result date)
I couldn't simply compare the two dates using WHERE results date > spec date because both spec's dates will be older then the result's date for the 2020-05-02.

Visual Example:
MySQL version 8.0.23. (It supports PARTITION OVER and WITH)

TABLE "TABLE_A": Containing the results of the quality control

| ID | Date | Result | Product | Spec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 24,5 | ProductA |  |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 25,5 | ProductA |  |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 31,4 | ProductA |  |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | 24.3 | ProductB |  |
| 5 | 2020-01-02 | 30.4 | ProductB |  |
| 6 | 2020-01-03 | 41.4 | ProductB |  |

**Data Type:** ID PrimaryKey Auto increment /
Date as Date() /
Results, Product and Specification as Varchar()

TABLE "TABLE_B": containing the required specification for each product - It can contain multiple rows for the same product since the specification can change over time.

| ID | Date | Spec | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 20.0 | ProductA |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 30.0 | ProductA |
| 3 | 2018-01-01 | 24.3 | ProductA |
| 4 | 2020-01-03 | 30.4 | ProductA |

**Data Type:** ID PrimaryKey Auto increment /
Date as Date() /
Product and Specification as Varchar()

THE EXPECTED OUTCOME WOULD BE:

| ID | Date | Result | Product | Spec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 24,5 | ProductA | 20.0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 25,5 | ProductA | 30.0 |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 31,4 | ProductA | 30.0 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | 24.3 | ProductB | 24.3 |
| 5 | 2020-01-02 | 30.4 | ProductB | 24.3 |
| 6 | 2020-01-03 | 41.4 | ProductB | 30.4 |

What I could come up with was the SELECT part, but it is only returning the Specs for the product that appears on both tables. I also needed to return NULL in case there is a product with results and yet no specification for it.

```
SELECT Table_C.Spec from Table_A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Product, Date, Spec from Table_B ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Table_C
ON Table_C.Product=Table_A.Product
WHERE Table_C.Date=(
SELECT max(Table_B.Date) FROM Table_B WHERE Table_B.Date<Table_A.Date and Table_A.Product=Table_B.Product) 
ORDER BY Table_A.ID
```

I hope the example is easier to understand this time.

Thank you,

Diogo

Comment: Don't materialize that at all. Else, you'll end up with redundant data and risk inconsistencies. You can always query the *guaranteed* right values. For convenience you can create a view when you don't want to repeat it every time.

Comment: Hi Strawberry. I was willing to have the specs at the same table of the results to make the statistical calculation I have to do latter a bit easier. The specs usually don't change in the past, so I don't have  to worry with past results. And for the new results I would automatically search for the respective specs the moment the results come in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is generally speaking much better served by creating a `VIEW`, than it is by merging the 2 datasets with an `UPDATE`.
That way both tables can continue to live on (unchanged) which means any application you may have, which writes to those tables, does not require changes.
That said, the actual heart of the query would be identical in either case, be it `CREATE VIEW AS` or `UPDATE`.

> The [examples of window
> functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)
> on this page may be helpful (especially the third example which
> introduces `PARTITION BY country`)
>
> Same for the [descriptions of
> CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions)
> (WITH-clause)

## Possible solution

This should be a working solution that does all you want,

```
CREATE VIEW 
     `TABLE_C`
AS
WITH `cteAllSpecs` AS (
        SELECT  A.`Product`                                    AS   `Product`
             ,  A.`Date`                                       AS   `TestDate`
             ,  A.`ID`                                         AS   `TestID`
             ,  B.`ID`                                         AS   `SpecID`
             ,    IF( B.`Date` <= A.`Date`, TRUE, FALSE)       AS   `SpecValid`
             ,    ROW_NUMBER()                OVER ( PARTITION BY A.`ID`, B.`Product`  ORDER BY B.`Date`    ASC, B.`ID` ASC)                                                          AS `Version`
             ,    COUNT(      B.`ID` )        OVER ( PARTITION BY A.`ID`, B.`Product`  ORDER BY B.`Product` ASC, B.`ID` ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS `Versions`
             ,    LAST_VALUE( B.`ID` )        OVER ( PARTITION BY         B.`Product`  ORDER BY B.`Product` ASC, B.`ID` ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS `LatestProductSpecID`
          FROM    `TABLE_A`                                    AS   `A`
    INNER JOIN    `TABLE_B`                                    AS   `B`
            ON  A.`Product` = B.`Product`


), `cteValidSpecs` AS (
        SELECT  E.* 
             ,    LAST_VALUE( E.`SpecID` )    OVER ( PARTITION BY   `TestID`           ORDER BY  E.`Version` ASC            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS `ActiveSpecID`
          FROM    `cteAllSpecs`                                AS   `E`
         WHERE    `SpecValid` IS TRUE


)       SELECT  A.*
             ,  B.`Spec`                                       AS   `Spec`
             , (B.`ID` IS NOT NULL)                            AS   `SpecDefined`
             ,  COALESCE(Y.`Version`,  0)                      AS   `Version`
             ,  COALESCE(X.`Versions`, 0)                      AS   `Versions`
             ,  Y.`ActiveSpecID`                               AS   `SpecID`
             ,  B.`Date`                                       AS   `SpecDate`
             ,  X.`LatestProductSpecID`                        AS   `LatestProductSpecID`
          FROM    `TABLE_A`                                    AS   `A`
     LEFT JOIN    `cteAllSpecs`                                AS   `X`  ON  A.`ID` = X.`TestID`
     LEFT JOIN    `cteValidSpecs`                              AS   `Y`  ON  A.`ID` = Y.`TestID`  AND X.`TestID` = Y.`TestID` AND Y.`SpecID` = Y.`ActiveSpecID`
     LEFT JOIN    `TABLE_B`                                    AS   `B`  ON  B.`ID` = Y.`ActiveSpecID`
      GROUP BY  A.`ID`
      ORDER BY  A.`Date`     ASC
             ,  A.`Product`  ASC
```

## How to use it

The query above will create a `VIEW` called `TABLE_C`.
A view behaves more or less just like a real `TABLE`, so you can just run

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_C
```

to see the content you were after.
Unlike `TABLE`s though, the `VIEW` doesn't really store things. You can keep running `INSERT`/`UPDATE` queries against your existing `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` and those changes will instantly also be reflected in the `TABLE_C` `VIEW`.

## Under the hood

As for how it works or what this all does, the `VIEW`'s query effectively works in 3 steps.

First we define a query named `cteAllSpecs`.

- Here, every Test (`TABLE_A`) is `INNER JOIN`ed together with every known Spec (`TABLE_B`) for that test's Product, though some columns are left out (no `Spec` text, no testresults).
- We use aliases to rename the columns, because your original tables conflict on `ID` and `Date`.
- Because we used an `INNER JOIN` any Tests for products without any known Spec are filtered out; Likewise, any Specs for products which have never been tested are filtered out.
- We temporarily define a new `SpecValid` BOOLEAN column; We'll consider any Spec for a Date **after** the Test's Date to NOT be valid for that Test. Any Spec dated `<=` the Test's date we'll consider valid (this means there could be multiple valid Specs for any given Test)
- Next we use Window functions to create 3 more temporary columns here (`Version`, `Versions` and `LatestProductSpecID`), those are the `OVER` `PARTITION BY` statements. These 3 actually are not required to accomplish what you wanted, but they may be a useful.
- The `Version` INT column is similar to `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `TABLE`s. It simply numbers the rows (Specs) from 1 to N; It numbers them partitioned *per Test*. So the 3 Specs for todays Test of Product A are numbered 1,2 and 3; while the 5 Specs for todays Test of Product B are numbered 1 to 5.
- The `Versions` INT column simply counts how many `Spec` records exist for the given Product (without caring about `SpecValid` or `Date`).
- The `LatestProductSpecID` column holds the `ID` for the absolute latest known spec for the given Product (again, without caring about `SpecValid` or `Date`).

So, to illustrate with an example:
Imagine, if there were a Product, for which the first Spec was registered on 1 September 2020, and a new revised Spec was added every single month (on the 1st), we would have 7 known Specs in `TABLE_B` for that Product.

This `cteAllSpecs` query would reflect the same by having those 7 rows, numbered as Version 1 to 7, for each single Test of that product.

### Under the hood (Part 2)

Next up, we define a very short query called `cteValidSpecs`.

`cteValidSpecs` actually runs the previous `cteAllSpecs` query, but it filters out all the rows that were not `SpecValid`. So a Test of the aforementioned product in late November, would only have rows for the first 3 Specs (Version 1/2/3), not the 4 "invalid" ones that are dated for Dec/Jan/Feb/Mar (Version 4/5/6/7).

In addition to that, it will define a temporary column named `ActiveSpecID` which contains the `ID` of the **newest valid** Spec. In the example above, that would be the `ID` for the version 3 row.

### Under the hood (Part 3)

And last but not least, there is the main query.

- Here we take the original `TABLE_A` data, and `LEFT JOIN` that together with both the `cteAllSpecs`-set (AS `X`) **and** the `cteValidSpecs`-set (AS `Y`).
- The fact that we use a `LEFT JOIN` here ensures every single `TABLE_A` row will be present now, even the ones for products which have no known Specs.
- The first 2 `LEFT JOIN`s give us access to the columns we created in those earlier queries.
- If (and only if) a given `TABLE_A` record had matching `Specs` in both the earlier queries, we'll use the `ActiveSpecID` value (`ID` for the most recent valid Spec) to also `LEFT JOIN` with `TABLE_B` and fetch the single correct `Spec` record.
- Now we have all the columns you desired, and in addition to that some extra:

`SpecID` is a renamed `TABLE_B`.`ID` (or `NULL` for Tests without a matching Spec).
`SpecDate` is a renamed `TABLE_B`.`Date` (or `NULL` for Tests without a matching Spec).
`SpecDefined` (BOOLEAN) indicates if the product for this Test had any data in `TABLE_B` at all or not (on the relevant Test Date; ignoring "future" Specs).

`LatestProductSpecID` (INT) indicates which `ID` in `TABLE_B` contains the absolute newest Spec record.

`Versions` (INT) indicates how many Specs (eg: `TABLE_B` records) are known for this product (this number includes future Specs). 0 means no Specs are known at all.

`Version` (INT) indicates which version/iteration of the specs applies to this Test. This value is 0 if there was no valid Spec; This value is 1 if the oldest `TABLE_B` record (for this product) was the newest at the time of the test. Minimum value 0. Maximum value equals `Versions`.

Comment: Thanks Raxi for the insights. I've just updated my example in the first post. I hope it's more understandable right now...

Comment: I've expanded my answer (above), with a functioning query and detailed break down.

Comment: Raxi, thank you so much. It worked like a charm.  Really thank you for taking the time to write this thorough answer. Helped me a lot.